# Convert Time to ISO 8601 format in UTC timezone

Tags: php

I have date as `Fri, 15 Mar 2019 08:56:57 +0000`

I want to convert this date in ISO 8601 format in UTC timezone in php.

I have tried the following:

```
$date = new DateTime("Fri, 15 Mar 2019 08:56:57 +0000");
$output = $date->format(\DateTime::ATOM);
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the ISO 8601 format you should use the `DateTimeInterface::ISO8601` in the format method, or you can use `"c"`:

```
$date = new DateTime("Fri, 15 Mar 2019 08:56:57 +0000");
echo $date->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
// will be 2019-03-15T08:56:57+0000
echo $date->format("c");
/* 
will be 2019-03-15T08:56:57+00:00
note the : in between hh and mm in offset(timezone)
generally accepted as valid ISO 8061 see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC
*/
```

Regarding the timezone if you want to force it into UCT timezone then you should  use the `setTimezone` method on the date object first with timezone param `"UTC"`:

```
$date = new DateTime("Fri, 15 Mar 2019 08:56:57 +0000");
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$output = $date->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Note about the above that if your original date time is not in UTC(has an offset) the time will be converted to UTC and the offset will be 0000:

```
$date = new DateTime("Fri, 15 Mar 2019 08:56:57 +0230");
echo $date->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
// will be: 2019-03-15T08:56:57+0230
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $date->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
// will be: 2019-03-15T06:26:57+0000
```